# Video too fast FFmpeg

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, frame-rate

I am having an issue again with ffmpeg, I'm a newbie with ffmpeg, and I can't find a good tutorial up to date...

This time, when I play a video with ffmpeg, it plays too fast, ffmpeg is ignoring the FPS, I don't want to handle that with a thread sleep, because the videos have differents FPS's.

I created a thread, there you can find the loop:

```
AVPacket framepacket;

while(av_read_frame(formatContext,&framepacket)>= 0){
    pausecontrol.lock();

    // Is it a video or audio frame¿?
    if(framepacket.stream_index==gotVideoCodec){
        int framereaded;
        // Video? Ok
        avcodec_decode_video2(videoCodecContext,videoFrame,&framereaded,&framepacket);
        // Yeah, did we get it?
        if(framereaded && doit){
            AVRational millisecondbase = {1,1000};
            int f_number = framepacket.dts;
            int f_time = av_rescale_q(framepacket.dts,formatContext->streams[gotVideoCodec]->time_base,millisecondbase);
            currentTime=f_time;
            currentFrameNumber=f_number;

            int stWidth = videoCodecContext->width;
            int stHeight = videoCodecContext->height;
            SwsContext *ctx = sws_getContext(stWidth, stHeight, videoCodecContext->pix_fmt, stWidth,
            stHeight, PIX_FMT_RGB24, SWS_BICUBIC, NULL, NULL, NULL);
            if(ctx!=0){
            sws_scale(ctx,videoFrame->data,videoFrame->linesize,0,videoCodecContext->height,videoFrameRGB->data,videoFrameRGB->linesize);
            QImage framecapsule=QImage(stWidth,stHeight,QImage::Format_RGB888);

            for(int y=0;y<stHeight;y++){
                memcpy(framecapsule.scanLine(y),videoFrameRGB->data[0]+y*videoFrameRGB->linesize[0],stWidth*3);
            }
            emit newFrameReady(framecapsule);
            sws_freeContext(ctx);
            }

        }
    }
    if(framepacket.stream_index==gotAudioCodec){
        // Audio? Ok
    }
    pausecontrol.unlock();
    av_free_packet(&framepacket);
}
```

Any Idea?

Comment: Can you obtain the FPS information from the video?

Comment: Yes. I can. Well, I have been looking in the internet, The thread sleep can be an option, any idea? I need to play the audio too, if I sleep the thread, the audio decoding will be aftected too...

Comment: I don't have any experience doing this, but is it possible to separate the rendering and the decoding step? (Rendering will sleep every 1/FPS second and then consume from decoded buffer, and decoding step will continue until buffer is filled up - consumer-producer kind of structure).

Comment: Hmm I can create a queue for the QImages and a queue for the audio, so the loop only inserts into the audio and images queue the information, then another timer or thread, gets the information of that queue and process it. But I'm worried about what can happens If I create a lot of threads or the audio or video can't play synchronized, do u recommned me this way?

Comment: I said before that I don't have any experience in doing this, so I'm mostly hand-waving here. I think you can 1) wait for expert to advice you 2) look at open source program that works well and see what they do 3) try yourself to see if there is any problem coming up.

Comment: Ok thanks. Sorry If I bothered you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use a delay based on the FPS value

```
firstFrame = true;
for(;;)
{
  //  decoding, color conversion, etc.

  if (!firstFrame)
  {
    const double frameDuration = 1000.0 / frameRate;
    duration_t actualDelay = get_local_time() - lastTime;
    if (frameDuration > actualDelay)
      sleep(frameDuration - actualDelay); 
  }
  else
    firstFrame = false;

  emit newFrameReady(framecapsule);

  lastTime = get_local_time();
}
```

`get_local_time()` and `duration_t` is abstract.

A more accurate method is to use a time stamp for each frame, but the idea is the same

Comment: Hey thanks for this. Any suggestions of what to do when the video is streamed over a network when the frames may arrive either too fast or too slow?

Comment: @Nav Just put received packets in the queue (in separate thread) and extract them as needed

Comment: @pogorskiy: thanks. The question was actually because if the stream is faster than the framerate that the video has to be played, then the queue would soon get full and one would have to drop frames which would make the video jump across many dropped frames. Was wondering how people handle that in case of a very large video file being streamed remotely (and assuming that frames arrive very fast). For a realtime stream from a webcam of course, the stream would be slow enough to show at the same rate.